# How can I get the View in the FileTransfer upload method in PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have created a native android app with PhoneGap + Sencha Touch 2. I have succeeded in uploading a file to the server, however, I am having a problem accessing a View from the upload success callback function in the FileTransfer upload() method. Here is my code:

upload callback:

```
uploadPicture: function(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions(),
    params = new Object(),
    fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(),
    builder = this.getBuilder(),
    app = this.getApplication(),
    uri = encodeURI('/myservlet');

options.fileKey = 'file';
options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = 'image/jpeg';

params.myparams = something;
params.moreparams = evenmore;

options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;

fileTransfer.upload(imageURI, uri, this.uploadSuccess.bind(this), this.uploadError.bind(this), options);        
},
```

upload success function

```
uploadSuccess: function (r) {
    var builderChild = this.getBuilderChild(),
    data = r.response.attachment;

builderChild.addInstance(builderChild.config, data);
navigator.notification.alert('Attachment successful.');
}
```

When I get into the uploadSuccess function my builderChild object is undefined. I have been able to use the builderChild object through this same Controller in other functions, but not in uploadSuccess.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, this is how I used to do it.

```
var ftSuccess = Ext.bind(this.uploadSuccess, this),
    ftError   = Ext.bind(this.uploadError, this);

fileTransfer.upload(imageURI, uri, ftSuccess, ftError, options);
```

Hope this helped

Comment: This works as well, however my problem was just decoding the response. Ext.decode(r.response)

Comment: I also use this.uploadSuccess.bind(this).